# Jenkins pipeline how to run build job with parameters from variables

Tags: jenkins, groovy, parameter-passing, pipeline

In jenkins pipeline I want to run "build job" using variables job_path and job_params.
`job_path = "long/path/to/different/jobs"`
`job_params = [string(name: 'app_one', value: '4.8.6')]` but more often
`job_params = "[string(name: 'app_one', value: '4.8.6'), string(name: 'app_three ', value: '1.2.4'), string(name: 'app_ten', value: '2.7.1')]"`

```
pipeline {
    stages {
        stage('Deployment') {
            steps {
                script {
                    build job: "${job_path}", parameters: job_params
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Path works perfect, but param don’t.
I get an error that a list is expected and a string is provided.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.BuildTriggerStep.setParameters() expects java.util.List<hudson.model.ParameterValue> but received class java.lang.String
```

and second one :

```
Also:   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.ErrorAction$ErrorId: xyz
Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate {job=long/path/to/different/jobs, parameters=[string(name: 'app_one', value: '4.8.6')]} for org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.BuildTriggerStep
```

I try cast this param variable to list,
Please advice me the best way to run job, pointed by path with random number of parameters.

Comment: show how you are assigning `list_param`. the error is quite clear `list_param` has string value instead of array...

Comment: @daggett the assignment is as in my question `list_param = [string(name: 'app_one', value: '4.8.6')]`, and it is undoubtedly a string value, can you tell me how to convert it to a list or what to do to make it work?

Comment: unfortunately without a code it's not possible to tell where exactly an issue. two guesses so far: `1/` you have declared `job_params` as string. `2/` you are transferring variable between stages/steps through environment variable that support only string values.

Comment: Hi @daggett param variable i take from remote storage (json file), param value is a string, but i can modify it. Now when i try to make it work i declare string variable in pipeline, so you are doubly right. `build job: "${job_path}", parameters: job_params` Maybe I'll better define the question, what the job_params variable should look like, but the number of parameters is unknown in advance and the key names and its value change. The form of the variable can be modified by me and will be loaded into the pipeline from an external file.

Answer (score 0):

you declare string:

`job_params = "[string(name: 'app_one', value: '4.8.6'), string(name: 'app_three ', value: '1.2.4'), string(name: 'app_ten', value: '2.7.1')]"`

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.BuildTriggerStep.setParameters() expects java.util.List<hudson.model.ParameterValue> but received class java.lang.String
```

[ParametersAction](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/ParametersAction.html) use list
`def List job_params = [ string(name: 'app_one', value: '4.8.6'), string(name: 'app_three ', value: '1.2.4'), string(name: 'app_ten', value: '2.7.1') ]`